# Move each value in a column to the next row in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays

I am building an array with the following code:

```
foreach ($something as $key => $row)
{
    $output[] = ["name" => $row["name"], "points" => $row["points"]];
}
print_r($output);
```

This produces the following array:

```
[
    ['name' => 'Mark', 'points' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Sara', 'points' => 2],
    ['name' => 'Jack', 'points' => 3],
]
```

I'm trying to move **$row["points"]** to the next row to get this output:

```
[
    ['name' => 'Mark', 'points' => null],
    ['name' => 'Sara', 'points' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Jack', 'points' => 2],
]
```

I don't care if there's some data loss or if my **[points] => 3** goes in a new array. I just have to programmatically move **$row["points"]** always to next element. I'm playing with **next()** function with no success and also with **$key+1** which I'm sure I can't use to achieve the result.

Is it possible to make it on top while I'm building the array or am I forced to move the element later with a separate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($something AS $key => $row)
{
    $output[$key]['name']       = $row["name"];
    $output[$key+1]['points']   = $row["points"];
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = array();
$point = '';
foreach($something AS $key => $row)
{
    $output[$key] = array("name"=>$row["name"], "points"=>$point);
    $point = $row['points'];
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $each)
{
    $array[0]['points'] = "";
    $array[$key]['name'] = $each["name"];
    if(isset($array[$key+1])) $array[$key+1]['points'] = $each["points"];
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Forward traversal of an indexed array to generate a new array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cpt1o))

   ```
   $result = [];
   foreach ($something as $i => $row) {
       $row['points'] = $something[$i - 1]['points'] ?? '';
       $result[] = $row;
   }
   var_export($result);
   ```

   Or: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hTXBD))

   ```
   $result = [];
   foreach ($something as $i => $row) {
       $result[] = array_replace(
           $row,
           ['points' => $something[$i - 1]['points'] ?? '']
       );
   }
   var_export($result);
   ```
2. Backward traversal of an indexed array to modify the input array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pFi0h))

   ```
   for ($i = array_key_last($something); $i >= 0; --$i) {
       $something[$i]['points'] = $something[$i - 1]['points'] ?? '';
   }
   var_export($something);
   ```
3. Forward traversal of an associative array to generate a new array without declaring each element individually: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OA020))

   ```
   $result = [];
   $points = null;
   foreach ($something as $key => $row) {
       $result[$key] = array_replace($row, ['points' => $points]);
       $points = $row['points'];
   }
   var_export($result);
   ```